# Error while applying Node Autoscaler for existing AKS cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to experiment with Preview feature available in Azure AKS as per documentation available we need to have the following requirements

- Kubernetes version 1.12.4 or later
- Azure CLI version 2.0.55 or later.
- add aks preview :- az extension add --name aks-preview
- register scale set provider:- az feature register --name VMSSPreview --namespace Microsoft.ContainerService
- ensure that it is registerd
  [image]
- created AKS cluster with terraform

when i try to apply following command

az aks update  --resource-group rg-euwest-d04-dvag-001 --name k8s-euwest-d04-dvag-dfs-dfsapp-001 --enable-cluster-autoscaler --min-count 3 --max-count 5

error

> Operation failed with status: 'Bad Request'. Details: AgentPool
>   '' has set auto scaling as enabled but is not on Virtual
>   Machine Scale Sets, this is not allowed

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, it is not supported at this time through terraform or from Azure Portal but only possible from  Azure CLI

Answer (score 0):

Your cluster needs to be created via Azure CLI to enable autoscaling. So if you have created on evia Azure portal, you need to delete it and create new one through Azure CLI. Ref: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/29199